# How a particle moves against a pressure gradient?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

[image]

This is a photo of a compressor together with a diffuser. These engine parts convert the kinetic energy of the air to static pressure and supply air to internal combustion engines.

The somewhat complicated geometry is due to the fact that air moves against a pressure gradient and the designer wants to avoid flow separation.

My question is why air moves at all?

If force is the reason of acceleration, how is possible to accelerate against a force?

Comment: An ultra-short answer:  The compressor _pushes_ it.  Slightly less short:  The particle is pushed by the compressor or, it is pushed by other particles that were pushed by the compressor or, ...by other particles that were pushed by other particles that were pushed by ... that were pushed by the compressor.

Comment: @jameslarge. Very funny, but the pressure downstreams is higher and poor compressor cannot" push" enough

Comment: @jameslarge. Life is not that simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to answer my own question.

The wheel is rotating. The rotating wheel is a non-inertial accelerating reference frame. The fictitious forces that arise in accelerating reference frames account for the force that pushes against static pressure.

Similar to when someone inflates a balloon: a field of velocities supports a field of static pressures.